# Rails formtastic - Edit form not passing instance to update method in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, formtastic

I have a form that I am using to 'edit' existing teams. Here is the view:

**/app/views/teams/edit.html.erb**

```
<%= semantic_form_for @team do |f| %>

  <%= f.inputs %>
  <%= f.actions %>

<% end %>
```

And here is the controller's code:

**/app/controllers/teams_controller.rb**

```
  def edit
    @team = Team.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    if @team.update_attributes(params[:team])
      redirect_to @team
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

However, when I go to /teams/1/edit and change the name of the team and click Update to submit the form, it gives the error: **undefined method `update_attributes' for nil:NilClass**

At the beginning of the update method in the controller, I did a:

```
raise @team.inspect
```

and my suspicion was proved correct when I saw that @team was inspected in the update method it was nil (i.e. it's value was not passed).

Does anyone know where I am going wrong here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need to define @team in the update action before you can use it.
Simply add this line to the beginning of the action:

```
@team = Team.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: D'OH! I feel stupid. Wasted so much time on something so trivial. Thank you sir.